# What does this equation about DNA replication mean?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-genetics, replication

Could someone help me understand this equation please? I found it in a paper which said that it was DNA replication, but why?

$\ce{dNTP + dNMP_{n} -> dNMP_{n +1} + PPi}$

I found that **dNTP** means *deoxy nucleotide triphosphate* and **dNTP** means *deoxy nucleotide monophosphate*. Deoxy nucleotide monophosphate is a monomer in DNA, but dNTP isn't.

I also would like to know if there is an equation like this in other processes in the central dogma (such as transcription and translation)?

Comment: NTP stands for nucleoside triphosphate. A subtle difference. With nucleotides, the phosphate is implied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation you are referring to is *a* way to express the elongation of a nucleotide strand (Fig. 1).

```
dNTP + dNMP(n) → dNMP(n+1) + PPi
```

means

**Existing strand  +  deoxynucleotidetriphosphate  →  elongated-strand  +  pyrophospate.**

[image: elongation]

<sup>Fig. 1. Elongation of DNA. Source: [Concepts in Genetics](http://bio3400.nicerweb.com/Locked/media/ch11/chain_elongation.html).</sup>

---

This reaction holds for DNA replication as well as transcription.

Translation is all about protein synthesis from amino acid precursors. Each subsequent amino acid is coupled to the growing peptide by a peptide bond between the carboxyl of the growing peptide and the amino group of the new amino acid. A water molecule is eliminated during the reaction (Fig. 2).

[image: peptide synthesis]
<sup>Fig. 2. Peptide bond formation. Source: [An Introduction to Molecular Biology](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Introduction_to_Molecular_Biology/Function_and_structure_of_Proteins)</sup>

Hence translation can be written analogously to replication as:

```
amino acid + peptide(n) → peptide(n+1)
```

However, also in this polymerization reaction energy is needed and amino acids are [activated](http://www.nobelprize.org/educational/medicine/dna/a/translation/trna_aminoact.html) while they are bound to the messenger RNA (mRNA) through the action of ATP. Moreover, during translation the [ribosome (i.e., the protein synthesizing machinery)](http://bscb.org/learning-resources/softcell-e-learning/ribosome/) uses another source of energy to move across the RNA template, namely GTP. Hence, the *net* reaction can be written as:

```
amino acid + peptide(n) + ATP + GTP → peptide(n+1) + AMP + GDP + PPi + Pi
```

Note that this notation in itself is *not* a dogma as other ways are in use to denote DNA and RNA synthesis. According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogma) a dogma is:

> A belief or set of beliefs that is accepted by the members of a group without being questioned or doubted.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that amino acids are not activated. tRNA charging is the activation step of protein synthesis and creates an ester bond with high and negative free energy of hydrolysis (whose cleavage subsequently drives peptide bond formation). tRNA charging requires ATP. A net equation for peptide synthesis could be written as `amino acid + peptide_n + ATP -> peptide_(n+1) + AMP + 2Pi`. This equation (like that discussed in the question) is over simplified, but gets the point across.

Comment: @canadianer - Great point, will include shortly

Comment: Additional point to what @canadianer said. Each elongation step requires a molecule of GTP per codon. So the reaction for translation elongation should be: `amino-acid + Peptide(n) + ATP + GTP → Peptide(n+1) + AMP + GDP + PPi + Pi`

Comment: @WYSIWYG - I edited the answer. Thanks. I must say that both mRNA activation and the ribosome movement are both indirectly related to the translation reaction. The direct substrates are mRNA and the growing peptide. ATP and GTP are indirectly involved. So I reverted to my old answer and added your comment alongside Canadianer's in a separate section for clarity's sake. Thanks for your suggestions and the edits!

Answer (score 0):

DNA is a polymer of dNMPs (dAMP, dTMP, dCMP, and dGMP). That's why you could describe DNA by dNMPn (n base length). When another dNTP is added to DNA (dNMPn), one pyrophosphate (PPi) is released. It is obvious that the length of the DNA results in n+1 bases.